# How do I import data from n number of csv files within a folder?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, if-statement, directory

[PYTHON HELP]

Hello, I would like some help figuring out how to import data from n number of files within a folder. When I try to extract the actual data I get an error stating that the file/directory does not exist.

```
import os, csv
path = ("my directory")
files = sorted(os.listdir(path)) 


def f():
    for file in (files):
         with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
                    data = csvfile.read
                    print(data)
```

> OUTPUT:

```
 File "<ipython-input-158-1f4c11da5a68>", line 1, in <module>
    f()
 File "<ipython-input-157-b977510dbfcd>", line 8, in f
    with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns just the file names, without their path names, so you would need to join the path names with the file names when you open them.

Change:

```
with open(file, 'r') as csvfile:
```

to:

```
with open(os.path.join(fcm_path, file), 'r') as csvfile:
```